# Insert foreign key

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into my table `alunos` using this code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO alunos (codaluno, nivel, Nome, turma, Estado, Morada, codpostal,Telefone, NIF, datanasc, Ano, Data_entrada, Data_saida, codescola, codpagamento, codpais) " +
               "VALUES (@codaluno, @nivel, @Nome, @turma, @Estado, @Morada, @codpostal, @Telefone, @NIF, @datanasc, @Ano, @Data_entrada, @Data_saida, @codescola, @codpagamento, @codpais);";

if(a.open_connection())
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, a.connection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codaluno", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@turma", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Estado", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Morada", textBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codpostal", textBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", textBox7.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIF", textBox8.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datanasc", textBox9.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ano", textBox10.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_entrada", textBox11.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data_saida", textBox12.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codescola", textBox13.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codpagamento", textBox14.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nivel", textBox15.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codpais", textBox16.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    a.close_connection();
}
```

but I get an error because of the foreign keys which in this case are "codescola" "codpagamento" "nivel" and "codpais".

This is the error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`edacademy`.`alunos`, CONSTRAINT `alunos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`codescola`) REFERENCES `escolas` (`codescola`))

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: As per the error, whatever value you are inserting into `codescola` doesn't have an entry in the `escolas` table. Check the value from `textBox13` and verify that it actually exists as a value in the `codescola` column of the `escolas` table

Comment: Kindly share your db structure also, so we can sort out the problem

Comment: Ok guys i sort out the problem, Martin was right.

Comment: Seeing code like "MySqlCommand" (datalayer) with code like "textBox1" (presentation layer) .. Please research "layered application development"  https://hub.packtpub.com/what-is-multi-layered-software-architecture/